# how to change the text value back to default when pressed again

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

I am creating an App using React Native, Where when I click the `GO` text, it is changing to the letter `X`. but, I also need to show `GO` text when I click back `X` again.


here is the code below

```
    this.state = {
    textValue:"You're Offile",
    cancel:'X',
    textGo:"GO",
    }
      onChange = () => {
        this.setState({
          textValue: 'Finding Rides',
          textGo:"X"
        });
      };
    
    
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onChange()}>
                  <Text 
                   //onPress={() => this.onChange()}
                  style={{
                    fontSize:30,
                    fontWeight:"bold",
                    color:"white"
                  }}>{this.state.textGo}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Please explain more about your issue.

Comment: this.state = {
textValue:"You're Offile",
cancel:'X',
textGo:"GO",
status:false,
}

onChange = () => {
if(!this.state.status)
    this.setState({
      textValue: 'Finding Rides',
      textGo:"X"
      state:true
    });
}else{
if(!this.state.status)
    this.setState({
      textValue: 'Finding Rides',
      textGo:"X"
      state:false
    });
}
};

Answer (score 1):

You can check condition in onChnage method and update your state according to it.

```
onChange = () => {

   if(this.state.textGo === "X")
   {
       this.setState({
         textValue: 'You're Offile',
         textGo:"GO"
       });
   }
   else
   {
       this.setState({
          textValue: 'Finding Rides',
          textGo:"X"
        });
   }
    
  };
```